# when creating user object for firebase database Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to retrive data from firebase. i was created a structure for user. but i am getting error in init method

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

```
struct userObj {
    var address:String!
    var name: String!
    var userId: String!
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var key: String!

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        name = snapshot.value!["name"] as! String   // this line give error
        address = snapshot.value!["address"] as! String // this line give error
        userId = snapshot.value!["userId"] as! String // this line give error
        ref = snapshot.ref
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely snapshot.value!["name"] is not a valid type. Try giving proper type.

Comment: name is string formate. so what's problem here??

Answer (score 1):

`DataSnapshot.value` property is declared as `var value: Any? { get }`

It is not explicitly declared as dictionary type, but it may contain dictionary among other possible types

- NSDictionary
- NSArray
- NSNumber (also includes booleans)
- NSString

Before you can access dictionary (if you know there is one) you have to typecast it to get the actual dictionary you can use:

```
snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
```

Please note that explicitly unwrapping optionals with `!` will crash if there is no appropriate data of appropriate type.